# How can I generate a 4 digit sequence based on and specific to a 16 digit sequence input by user?

Tags: php, mysql

> `I am working on a system where a user inputs a 16 digit code(A) and the server outputs a 4 digit code(B) based on the user input code. The algorithm used to generate the 4 digit code(B) is based on the 15th and 16th digits of the user input code(A).`
> Here are a few examples of code B being generated from code A:
> `A(0B3D72606A620646) = B(6666) A(A18BDCCEC4CCA933) = B(1313) A(11F5796B61690196) = B(B6B6)`
> Here is a summary of the criteria followed while generating B from A:
> `Permitted characters(0-9 and A-F)
> 15th digit of code A is used to generate 1st digit of code B following these equivalencies; if 15th digit of A is 0, 1st digit of B is 2; if 15th digit of A is 1, 1st digit of B is 3; 15th of A is 3, 1st of B is 1; 15th of A is D, 1st of B is F. And so on, covering all permitted characters.
> 16th digit of A is always equal to 2nd digit of B.

After getting digits 1 and 2 of code B, they are repeated to make 4 digits for example if digits 1 and 2 of code B are C and 6, the four digits of code B will be C6C6.`
I would like to put all this in PHP code that can be executed whenever a user inputs code A, code B is generated and displayed.

I have been generating code B manually using above algorithm, so far I have been unable to find a solution thats even worth mentioning, all methods for string generation i have come across and tried do not base on a different string to generate and are mostly random generators, yet what i require is a code unique to one input by a user.

Comment: This sounds like a student assignment? Here you need to write your own code, you won't find a complete example online. For some ground rules see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: You can't say and so on when there is no obvious way that the outcome is achieved..why for example does a0 go to b2, a1 go to b3 then a3 suddenly drop back to b1. That's not an algorithm that;s mapping

Answer (score 1):

I would create an array for the substitution:

```
$sub = array('0'=>'2', '1'=>'3', '3'=>'1', 'D'=>'F'); // etc.
```

which will allow you to easily generate the first character of B based on the input A. The rest is simple to do as it's just copying characters directly.